# Failed to load PDF Document | APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

When I try to print or download a Classic or Interactive Report from Oracle APEX, I get this message:

[image: Failed to load PDF document - RELOAD]

Answer (score 1):

To get a PDF file, you have to set up Oracle BI Publisher, or ORDS server to process the xml output.  Try downloading the "PDF" file, then open in a text editor.  If it's just a bunch of XML, then you don't have a FOP server set up.